# Is there any way to Firebase Auth twice in the same App instance?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

Specifically this is for iOS but this could and WILL be relevant to an Android app as well.

I have an app in production use with a login portion that only loads if the user isn't auth'd. Now, I was wondering if I can have have 2 layers of this.

I'm currently checking if the currentUser is nil/null. If not, then I proceed. If so, I take the user to a login view.

I want to essentially have the user login 2 times if 2 layers are both signed out. But in this form:
UserA -> UserA-1

So if user isn't logged into UserA then they can't be logged into UserA-1, if that makes sense.

I'm not sure if Firebase has something already made to handle this or if I have to make my own. If the latter, i'm curious as to what approaches you guys have taken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's only possible to have a single user signed in at one time for one app instance.  Signing in a second user will implicitly sign out the prior user.

Comment: Thought so. Any thoughts or points of direction for a solution to this?

Comment: To be honest, I can't tell what problem you're trying to solve by having two sign-ins at the same time.  Maybe post to Reddit to start a discussion.  https://www.reddit.com/r/Firebase/

Comment: I actually did right before you replied!

Essentially I want to have GlobalUser and LocalUser. GlobalUser signs in once to access global functionality then multiple LocalUsers can sign in and depending on the local user, will have MORE functionalities than the regular global functionalities.

The specific use case might require me to have this user layering but i'm still talking that over.

Comment: It sounds like this might be better implemented using per-user configurable security controls, maybe using custom claims.  What you're describing isn't an expected use case for Firebase Auth.

Comment: Yeah so conversation that i'm having with myself is whether to force use custom claims since the specific use case might require this user layering. Either way, thanks for the help Doug!