# How to use multiple Firestore instances in one application with "if request.auth != null" rule?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I have an app built on the Firebase Web SDK.

The app mainly uses a "primary" Firebase project, with Auth and Firestore setup on it.

But I also have a "secondary" Firebase project with Firestore setup. And I want to access those Firestore docs within the primary app.

As [per the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/multiprojects) I can easily add access the second Firestore like this:

```TypeScript
const secondAppConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.FIREBASE_SECOND_PROJECT_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.FIREBASE_SECOND_PROJECT_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.FIREBASE_SECOND_PROJECT_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.FIREBASE_SECOND_PROJECT_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.FIREBASE_SECOND_PROJECT_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.FIREBASE_SECOND_PROJECT_APP_ID,
};

export const secondApp = initializeApp(secondAppConfig, "second");
export const secondFirestore = getFirestore(secondApp);
```

But it only works when the second Firestore has rules that allow **anyone** to read:

```TypeScript
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      // allow read: if request.auth != null; // This does not work
      allow read: if true;
      allow write: if false;
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to change this to `allow read: if request.auth != null;` so that only logged in users can read the Firestore docs.

But this does not work. I get a console error saying `Error: Missing or insufficient permissions`.

I think the error is because the user is logged in on the primary app, not the secondary app, so `request.auth` is `null` and permission is denied.

So how can I allow reading of the second Firestore project only when the user is logged in on the primary Firestore project?

Maybe I can pass the `request.auth` object along somehow?

Comment: Can you have a second [`getAuth()` instance](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth) that uses the same credentials and signs the user in to the other project? This was said to be [not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58919234/3784008) but I think that answer assumes it's a single `getAuth()` instance, not a wholly separate one managing that user state separate from the primary instance.

Comment: @anothermh Do you mean duplicate each user on signup (once is primary project and once in secondary project) and then log the user into both projects using two instances of `getAuth()`? I would rather not have the overhead of keeping two Firebase Authentication instances in sync like that. But maybe I misunderstood what you are saying.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm saying: sync the users between the projects and when they sign into the primary one sign them into the secondary one as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any way to Firebase Auth twice in the same App instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58919107/is-there-any-way-to-firebase-auth-twice-in-the-same-app-instance)

Comment: @MarcAnthonyB that question you linked is described really really bad, but from reading the comments I think it is about custom claims on a single project. That is different to what I am asking here. I want to login a single user into two projects at once. Please remove the close request because it doesn't apply here.

Comment: The question @MarcAnthonyB linked isn't actually a bad question, it just doesn't apply to *this* question. Why do you feel the second project must have *rules that allow anyone to read*? Each project has its own set of rules and you will need to authenticate the user into the project whose data you want to access and you would need to have separate firebase instances.

Comment: @Jay At the moment I think I have two options. 1) Make the Secondary project open so everyone can read, as shown in the original question. 2) Maintain two user databases, and sign up and login the user into both projects each time, as suggested by @anotherm in the comments. But keeping multiple user databases in sync will become messy. Rather, I was hoping to make a rule that says "when user from Primary project is logged in allow read access to Secondary project documents". I thought this could be done by sharing the `request.auth` object from one project to another, but I guess not.

Comment: While you can authenticate a user to Firebase instance 1, and then also authenticate them to Firebase instance 2 (giving a user access to both), each Firebase has it's own set of rules - which makes sense since each Firebase would or could also have it's own structure. It's not clear why that's an issue and the bigger question; why attempt to keep two Firebases in sync? Why not just have one Firebase?

Comment: @Jay I have many Firebase projects, each with their own Firestore docs and user database. And in addition I also have an admin project that has a Firestore which is shared by all the other projects. That way I can update the shared Firestore once and all other projects will be updated at the same time.

Comment: In what way are you 'sharing the admin project...' with the other projects? How are changes made to the admin project rolling out to the others? Are you using built in functionality or something you crafted?

Comment: @Jay The admin project has a Firestore document that I am using in all my other projects. And I am accessing that shared admin document by adding a second Firestore instance (code details for this shown in the question). The document contains some short descriptions and other bits and pieces that all of the other projects use. So when I need to change something in that shared Firestore document all my other projects automatically reflect the change. This saves me having to update it in all of the projects one by one.

Comment: OK, makes sense. You've got one Firebase that shares data with other firebases. The error in the question directly results from not having rules set up for the user to access their data. What's preventing that from happing? Why not set up rules in each Firebase so when a user authenticates to that firebase, they can access their data?

Comment: @Jay The primary goal is to avoid maintaining separate user databases for each project, as well as having to authenticate users separately for each project. I am trying to find a solution that allows users authenticated in the primary project to access the shared Firestore documents in the secondary (admin) project without having to duplicate the authentication process for the secondary project. Ideally, I want to create a rule in the secondary project that grants read access to users authenticated in the primary project without having to authenticate them separately in the secondary project.

Comment: Understood. I could be totally wrong here, but unfortunately, I don't believe that's possible. Rules apply to a single Firebase only and that provides isolation between Firebase projects (and developers). i.e. Rules for Firebase A cannot control access on Firebase B. That being said, and I haven't attempted this, the authentication process should be able to be automated so it's transparent to the user, if that's the concern.